# How ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:0 can be fixed?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I need to use dynamic data structure during generation of matrix, but eventually matrix is shown like the list, which is very uncomfortable to see.
That's why I decided to add 2D array.
But when I launch this, I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 error. Tried everything, but it still doesn't work. Any ideas how it can be corrected ?

```
List<Integer> J = null;
static int ord;
static int ord1;
static int notZero;
static int val=0;
public static int[][] array;


public Matrix(){
    int numberCol;
    A=new LinkedList<ElementStructure>();
    x=new LinkedList<ElementStructure>();
    b=new LinkedList<ElementStructure>();
    J = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    array = new int[ord][ord];
    Random rand= new Random();
    System.out.print("Enter matrix order ");
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    ord = scn.nextInt();
    ord1=ord/2;
    for (int i=0; i<ord;i++){
        for( int j=0; j<ord; j++){
            if(j==ord-i-1){
                J.add(j);
                int q = rand.nextInt(201)-100;
                A.add(new ElementStructure(i,j,q));
                array[i][j] = q;
                val++;
                break;
            }   else if(ord<20){notZero=ord/2;}
            else { notZero=rand.nextInt(ord);}
            for(int k=0; k<notZero; k++){
                numberCol=rand.nextInt(ord);
                if(J.contains(numberCol)){continue;}
                    J.add(numberCol);
                    int q = rand.nextInt(201)-100;
                    A.add(new ElementStructure(i,numberCol, q));
                    array[i][numberCol] = q;
                    val++;
            }
            break;
        }
}

}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Matrix Matrix = new Matrix();
    for (int c=0; c<Matrix.val; c++){
        System.out.println(Matrix.A.get(c).toString());
    }
    for (int i = 0;i < ord;i++){
        for (int j = 0;j < ord;j++){
            System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
        }
    System.out.println();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Your array has a length of zero. After the first initialization of the array you can't change it's size anymore. You initialize it with `[0][0]`

Comment: Thanks a lot , code is working now

Answer (score 0):

You should declared the next line after assign a value to ord because you are initializing your array with ord with a 0, thats why the length of your array is 0 and provokes you the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
array = new int[ord][ord];
```